# Could not load file or assembly System.Data.SQLite - Windows application

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, dll

I am trying to use the SQLite's .Net DLL to access some data on a local SQLite database. The problem is that i need a way arround this error because i need to develop a software for 32/64 bits platforms (by using VB.Net not C#).

How can i stick to the 32bit version of the DLL to allow 32bit users of my program use it too?

If it's not possible to work with the 32bit version of SQLite's DLL, is it possible to include both versions in my Installer and programaticly choose which version of the DLL should be used?

Or..is there any other way to access SQLite databases without this particular DLL? (Things in C/C++ are much easier when it comes to SQLite usage as i remember)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your Target Platform to x86 instead of AnyCPU your code will be emitted as 32bit code also on 64bit systems and you could use just the 32bit dll of SQLite.
If you think that you are loosing some value working exclusively with x86 then I can give you [this reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/09/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx) where the PRO and CONS of AnyCpu are critically examined.

To change the Target Platform use:

Menu `BUILD`, then `Configuration Manager`
Choose `x86` from the `Active Solution Platform` combo.

If you don't have an x86 choice,
choose `New` and Select `x86` and copy the default settings from `AnyCpu`.

Comment: If you don't have any specific reason to work with AnyCPU switch to x86, x86 apps works with 64bit Operating Systems and can use 32bit DLL so there is no need to distribute the 64bit version of SQLite

Comment: Works with x86! Thanks so much!